# Electron BrowserWindow content issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have a problem with electron `BrowserWindow` when page loaded any content does not appear How can i fix this?

```
var nodeConsole = require('console');
var console = new nodeConsole.Console(process.stdout, process.stderr);

   var BrowserWindow = require('electron').remote.BrowserWindow;
   var win = new BrowserWindow({ show : true,width: 1920, height: 1080 });
   var ipcMain = require("electron").remote.ipcMain;



   win.loadURL('https://www.binance.com');

    win.webContents.on('dom-ready', function (e) {

      win.webContents.executeJavaScript(`

      var ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;


          var i = document.getElementsByClassName("ng-binding ng-scope")[106].innerText;


        function start(){
          var value=i;

          ipcRenderer.send('query', value);

        }
        setInterval(start,2500);

      `);
    });
```

[enter link for image](https://ibb.co/dnSgHc)

Comment: I think your mixing up things. When you use remote within your renderer process it is a sign that you maybe should place your code with in your main process and send a message from the render process to the main process to execute the action. Furthermore ipcMain is intended to communicate from the main process with the render process and  ipcRenderer for the render process to communicate with the main process.

Comment: for example i trying to load script on google and read any value or dom object and send to index.html , i can read but which website using angular js or another think  browser not show content. I cant read any variable or dom objects

Comment: Take a look here https://github.com/hokein/electron-sample-apps/tree/master/webview/browser it's an example browser.